# Without wind, would a plane go straight if the pilot let go of the controls?

Tags: flight-controls, stability, flight-dynamics, airplane, fixed-wing

If you let go of the steering wheel of a (properly maintained) car, it will typically go in a straight or nearly straight line. Would a powered airplane in no-wind conditions do the same thing?

Comment: Consider this example, where the pilot not only lets go, but departs the aircraft!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornfield_Bomber

Comment: @DJohnM - post cornfield, I worked on that particular jet at Griffiss AFB, 49th FIS. It now resides at the museum at Wright-Pat.

Comment: Can you say why planes might not do that?

Are planes not bound by the first law of motion, saying that a body continues in a state of rest or uniform motion in a straight line, unless acted upon by a(n external) force?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin gravity is an external force, and I didn't know if the plane would stay up on its own. Gravity (mostly) isn't an issue for cars in this case because they're supposed to be down on the ground.

Comment: It's good that you realised gravity was an external force and then what?

Whether a plane might stay up on its own depends on gravity only if all other things are equal. Otherwise, it depends on the inequalities.

Yes, if you let go of a car's steering wheel it will typically go in a (nearly) straight line.

Yes, planes do the same, the difference being the number of dimensions.

Cars go forward or back, left or right but neither up nor down.

Planes go forward or back, left or right and both up and down.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin exactly; I assumed a plane would keep going forward and not turn left or right if the pilot let go of the controls, but I didn't know whether or not it would stay at a constant altitude, because that's a factor that isn't relevant to cars, and I didn't know how gravity or the lift of the plane would affect it. Sorry if my questions don't make a lot of sense; I don't know much at all about how planes work.

Comment: @Someone When you assumed a plane would keep going forward and not turn left or right if the pilot let go of the controls, but you didn't know whether it would stay at a constant altitude, why did you let cars limit your thoughts?

When you didn't know how gravity or "the lift of the plane" would affect it, why would it not have been a good idea to compare the plane's movement in three dimensions to a car's movement in two? Why would "up or down" differ from "forward or back" or "left or right"?

If those queries don't matter, why are you Asking?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Up/down is fundamentally different from left/right or forward/back (at least where gravity exists), because gravity is creating a downward force external to the object. Without wind, there is no such force in the horizontal plane (no pun intended).

Comment: “Without wind, there is no such force in the horizontal plane”.  Please read the second paragraph of my answer and try to let the meaning sink in.  (Hint:  Imagine standing in the gondola of a hot air balloon drifting over the ground at 10 knots.  Would you feel 10 knots of “wind” on your face?)

Comment: @MichaelHall so "without wind" should be "without changes in wind speed or direction"?

Comment: @Someone Can you say what difference it makes if we're looking at a powered plane or a glider?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_plane

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin a glider will, well, glide down. It certainly can't stay level. Apparently most powered planes do stay level without input, but I didn't know that before asking this question.

Comment: @Someone Military gliders are designed to fall safely - though they often don't. Civilian gliders are designed to use the air currents around them, the idea being to rise: ask a glider pilot.

They do that by using what you might call "up-winds", generally know as "thermals."

If you see thermal up-winds as different to left or right or head or tail winds, how does that work?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin so a civilian glider would just fall, not glide, with no wind?

Comment: @Someone Absolutely not. Why would you think that off your own bat, let alone when I'd already told you civilian gliders are designed to use the air currents around them, the idea being to rise: ask a glider pilot.

Why do you not accept that they do that by using what you might call "up-winds", generally know as "thermals." If you see thermal up-winds as different to left or right or head or tail winds, how does that work?

Comment: We are getting into the weeds here, but effects of wind depends on whether by "go straight" you are asking about maintaining a constant ground track, or a constant heading.  (Or a constant altitude if you are considering vertical "wind" in the form of thermals, updrafts, turbulence, etc.)

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, can you explain what you mean by:  "Military gliders are designed to fall safely - though they often don't."?  P.S.  The OP didn't say they didn't accept that glider pilots could use thermals to gain altitude, only that they weren't aware.  Not too uncommon or surprising if your glider experience is limited to throwing paper airplanes...

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I specified "without wind" in the title, so any scenario involving wind is irrelevant. I was thinking of powered planes, not gliders, although I did not specify that.

Comment: @MichaelHall is right; I believe you when you say gliders use thermals to climb; I just didn't know that before you said it.

Comment: @MichaelHall Risking exile to Chat, do you see no difference between great and little details of gliding, and Someone's Question?

Broadly, civilian gliders are crafted for the joy of flight; military gliders to be towed to a target then released to fall to ground… often, disastrously.

OP did say (he?) wasn't aware gliders could use thermals to gain altitude and if one is approaching a Question like this from a perspective like that, why should one not be expected to treat up and down in the same way as left and right or for and aft?

Is this about experience, logic or neither?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I don't consider chat to be exile, but rather an excellent forum for continuing fruitful conversations!  That said, I'm not totally sure of your point...  I am familiar with historical military gliders, but I don't believe them relevant to the question at hand because I am not aware of any being in use in the last 3/4 of a century or so.

Comment: @MichaelHall Good for you, and where did your "3/4 of a century or so" rule originate, please? Why would anyone mind?

I was working on known historical experience. What were you working on?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin even without wind, up/down seems like it would be different because of gravity. (My pronouns are he/him).

Comment: Yes, of course. The point is that with or without wind, up/down will be different because of gravity.

If you think back to first principles, how might up/down be different because of gravity?

At the same time, how might left/right or fore/aft be different because of gravity?

Are those principles muddy?

Comment: Why are telling us "My pronouns are he/him", please? If you have doubts about your gender or sexuality, are there not many counsellors available?

If you have no doubts, why not use ordinary English?

If you see a third possibility, what is that, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin you said "OP did say (he?) wasn't aware gliders"; I thought the parentheses and question marks meant you weren't sure which pronouns to use, and I was confirming that you got them right. I'm not questioning my gender; I was just clarifying something I thought you weren't sure about.

Comment: I wouldn't expect fore/aft and left-right to be affected by gravity if the plane is level and balanced.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, I have no "rule", so I don't know what you mean...  Are there any military gliders currently in use?  Whether there are or not, what is the relevance to this question?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin what did you mean by putting "he" in quotes with a question mark? I never tell people my pronouns normally; this was the first time I ever did it, and I did because I thought you asked.

Comment: @MichaelHall You said you don't believe historical military gliders to be relevant to the question… not having being in use in the last 3/4 of a century or so. Not be facetious, if that wasn't as close you could get "ruling them out", the time lapse would not change the way mechanics or physics work.

Comment: By the way, I'm sorry I didn't notice this before and I, for one should have been saying "straight and level" throughout.

Comment: Gliders in general aren't really relevant to my question; it's about powered airplanes.

Comment: Yes, what the OP said.  And not considering something relevant to a question due to length of elapsed time, limited sample size, history of failure, etc. isn't the same thing as a hard and fast "rule" as you described it.  But if there is something specific about military gliders that you believe enhances our understanding about aircraft stability then please write it into an answer.

Comment: Broadly, it is a simple question about stability.  (Are airplanes stable?  Y/N)  Some background on different types of stability, or trim, is appropriate in any answer, but I it wasn't a category or class question and I think we can let this go...

Comment: P.S.  @Someone, I notice you haven't accepted an answer, do you feel any are lacking?

Comment: @MichaelHall thanks for the reminder; I accepted one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Just to add something to the already given answers.***

---

Hands-off, an airplane is stable but it moves a bit around this stability.

As already explained, if the airplane is stable (inherently or artificially) and trimmed then it is going to fly just dead straight. Anyway even within this boring flight path there exist "stable-instabilities" which are not necessarily triggered by wind/gust and which are going to give a

> nearly straight

flight path.

Let's consider a jetliner and let's say that, due to whatever reason (except obviously wind/gust: pilot nudges on the pedals, turbolence over airplane's surface is not perfectly symmetrical among left and right side, ...), it yaws a bit nose-right. The [following picture](https://blog-aviationclass.blogspot.com/2016/09/aviation-knowledge.html?m=1) shows this  yaw in an exaggerated manner:

[image: swept wing with yaw]

What happen now? Well, as said the airplane is stable so it somehow reacts to this initial yaw trying to return to its straight position... but not that simply. Qualitatively:

1. Drag and lift generated on the left wing possess now a bigger leverarm in respect to the CG and therefore the left wing tends to go up (bigger lift's leverarm) and back (bigger drag's leverarm) creating a left-up roll and a yaw opposite to the initial yaw.
2. The left wing rotates/moves against the airflow and therefore its local airspeed increases, while on the right wing the local airspeed decreases. Bigger speed means bigger lift and drag and therefore the left wing tends to go up (bigger lift) and back (bigger drag) creating a left-up roll and a yaw opposite to the initial yaw (just like in 1.)
3. The vertical stabiliser possesses now an AoA different from zero and produces a lateral force. This lateral force is also acting against the initial yaw but!
4. It is also located above the CG (seen from the back) and it creates therefore a left-up roll as well.
5. Due to this roll, the local AoA on the lowering right wing increases while on the rising left wing, it decrease. Lift becomes therefore bigger on the right wing and this bigger lift opposes to the initial roll and levels the airplane off.

That's a lot of events for only a light nudge on the pedals. And it is not yet the end of the story: these restoring yaw and roll don't make only the airplane go back to a straight flight but they actually make the airplane overshoot it's initial straight condition. The airplane continues the yaw and the roll movement on the other side! And then, since it is stable, backward again! This [nice picture](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DutchRollAnimGIF02.gif#mw-jump-to-license) depicts this "stable instability":

[image: Dutch roll]

It is called Dutch roll and it is one of the few typical and well known "dynamic modes" of airplanes.

So, hands-off an airplane is stable but it moves a bit around this stability.

Answer (score 32):

If the airplane is properly trimmed, the airmass is smooth, and the aircraft is inherently stable in its design, then yes - many airplanes are capable of flying straight with only very light and occasional inputs.  In fact pilots are trained to trim so that very little correction is needed to maintain straight and level flight.

P.S. "Wind" is simply the relative movement of a mass of air across the surface of the earth.  This concept is lost on the airplane, that knows only its own movement through this airmass.  The airplane responds only to instability of the airmass in the form of turbulence, gusts, or windshear, all of which have the potential to upset its equilibrium.  The conditional statement "without wind" is actually irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Read "without wind" as "without gusts" and the term becomes relevant indeed. +1

Comment: @Peter, your comment is also relative. In the frame of reference of the airmass, gusts are also irrelevant. Changing the velocity of the wind (the relative velocity of the airmass frame of reference with respect to the ground) will not change the direction of a body moving in the airmass. And even if you fly through a wind shear where the airmass suddenly starts moving in a different direction, the inertia of a body with mass causes it to continue moving in the direction it is already moving in. (One of Newton's laws) It will simply weathervane to align itself with the new *relative* wind.

Comment: Of course, if you *mix* metaphors (or concepts) by performing mental analysis in more than one frame of reference at the same time (the ground, *and* the airmass), then it is easy to become confused. Considering the path of a body in a frame of reference other than the one the body is moving in creates the perception that it is changing direction, when in its frame of reference, it is simply changing the magnitude of its velocity, (slowing down) not its direction. Throwing something out of a moving car is a great example. @Michael, your P.S. is spot on.

Comment: @CharlesBretana No, gusts are relevant because the airplane does not fly into them all at once. Instead, local angle of attack varies over length and/or span, depending how the gust is shaped and how it is entered and exited. This will upset a trimmed airplane.

Comment: I would lump gusts and turbulence together.  Both contribute to unstable air upsetting the aircraft.  That was my point anyway, I think we may be splitting hairs here…

Comment: The more abruptly an aircraft transitions from one airmass into another moving at a different velocity relative to the ground (read a *gust*), the more rapidly the gust will affect the aircraft.  But regardless of how rapidly the transition occurs, it will not (it cannot), change the inertial direction of motion. Aircraft have mass, therefore they have inertia, which means that unless a force is applied to them, they will maintain their inertial direction of motion. Any change in *wind* will only cause a weathervane effect. It only changes the direction it is pointed in.

Comment: ... and the only *force* that might cause such a change in direction would be from the sideways force imparted by the relative wind when the aircraft is in a sideslip. And this force, when adjusting to a gust, is small, (it is dependant on the magnitude of the sideslip angle), and extremely short- lived.

Comment: Worth noting that many large aircraft exhibit extremely slow spiral mode instability due to the large vertical stabiliser, which is there to damp Dutch roll (which tends to make people sick!).  So with no hands on the controls, such an aircraft will very slowly enter a tighter and tighter spiral.

Comment: I think gusts are very relevant. An aircraft should be stable and return to it's equilibrium after a small disturbance, but if the disturbance is big enough, every aircraft will be unstable.

Comment: If "fly straight" refers to track, then wind can make an aircraft not fly straight.

Comment: @Acccumulation, I agree.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Most aircraft are designed to be inherently stable.  That is, if you just let go of the controls, the aircraft will return to whatever it is *trimmed* to - typically stable and level flight.

Trims are redundant controls (rudder, elevator, ailerons) which are controlled by a "set-and-stay" knob rather than a dynamically movable yoke or pedals.  Turning the elevator trim knob has the same effect as pushing or pulling the yoke, for instance.  So if the pilot wants to hold a rate of climb or descent (often 0), they set the trim knob rather than use muscle to hold the yoke, which would be fatiguing.

If the trims are used conventionally, the pilot doesn't need to hold the yoke at all, and the airplane will keep doing what the trims are set to do, typically straight and level flight.

Generally, aircraft which *are not* inherently stable will inherently fall off-center, which will cause a vicious cycle and will rapidly exceed flight maximums.  They must be kept at center by constant correction.  The workload involved is generally too intense for pilots, so they must have some sort of automation to do it for them.

Comment: Gliders will often show unstable phygoid and spiral dive modes. Still, pilots will fly them without problems because those instabilities evolve slowly.

Comment: Large jets tend to exhibit unstable spiral modes too because of their large vertical stabilisers, but again, the modes are so slow that they pose no problems for a pilot.

Answer (score 8):

The real answer is that it would fly fairly straight. This was realised by the Wright brothers who were bicycle makers.

Both for bicycles and aircraft you have a choice between stability and manoeuverability. Some very early aircraft were too stable. Set on a straight course into a hillside they would follow it. The ideal is to be slightly unstable with a long natural period. That way a straight course can be imposed, by pilot or autopilot, with very little exertion, but if a turn is needed it can be done quickly

Answer (score 3):

If the airplane is configured to fly straight and level, then it'll remain that way until the pilot decides to touch the controls. This is especially true if the aircraft has an autopilot system. In a no wind scenario, the airplane will settle in straight and level flight at a particular angle of attack at a given airspeed. As long as the aircraft elevator can be trimmed to maintain this angle of attack, then the pilot will not have to give pressure to the yoke. If the air was not 100% calm, then adjustments may have to be made, but depending on the positive stability of the aircraft, it'll stabilize and regain straight and level flight. So the answer to your question is, generally yes.

Answer (score 1):

There are many airplanes which will eventually tend to slowly roll into a banked turn if the pilot lets go of the controls (and takes his or her feet off the rudder pedals) in smooth air. If the aircraft is truly perfectly trimmed in roll, and the air is free of gusts (not wind-- a steady wind is irrelevant), then the direction of the roll and turn (left vs right) will be random.

An airplane's tendency to stay wings-level with no control inputs is called "roll stability" or "lateral stability".

Design features that tend to enhance roll stability include dihedral, sweep, and a high-mounted wing.  Design features that tend to make an aircraft unstable in roll ("spirally unstable") include a low-mounted wing, a long wingspan (because if the airplane starts to turn at all, the outboard wingtip describes a larger radius and thus experiences more airspeed and generates more lift than the inboard wingtip), and a very large vertical fin (because it minimizes sideslip in turning flight, and sideslip is fundamental to how dihedral, sweep, and high-wing placement all contribute to roll stability.)

Examples of aircraft that will eventually roll into a banked turn in the absence of control inputs from the pilot (or autopilot), even when flying in smooth air and trimmed to be perfectly balanced in roll, include nearly all sailplanes (and motorgliders), and all purpose-designed aerobatic airplanes with a mid-wing configuration with zero dihedral.  All modern hang gliders also exhibit this behavior -- earlier "Rogallo" designs did not, and would stay wings-level when flown for extended periods without the pilot touching the control bar.

In an aircraft that tends to roll into a turn when flown hands-off, as the bank angle increases, the airspeed (and therefore the wing loading, which is essentially lift force per unit weight) tends to increase.<sup>1</sup>  The flight path tends to descend.  The result is often called a "diving spiral".  In some cases-- but not in all cases-- in the absence of further control inputs from the pilot, the bank angle will tend to reach a maximum value and stop increasing before the aircraft is damaged.  In other cases, in the absence of pilot intervention, the aircraft is likely to be damaged or destroyed either due to overloading, or due to aerodynamic flutter from overspeeding.

I suppose that in theory, if the air were *absolutely* smooth (free of gusts), and the test were initiated with the wings *perfectly* level, an airplane that was trimmed to be *perfectly* balanced in roll would not ever enter a turn, even if it had a configuration such that it was inherently unstable in roll.  But those conditions are never present in reality.  To expect this to happen in the real world, would be like expecting a nail balanced on its point on a hard marble slab to stay vertically upright, because there is no reason for it to fall in any one particular direction.  In the real world, to stay wings-level indefinitely in the absence of corrective inputs from the pilot or autopilot, and not eventually roll into a turn, an airplane must have positive lateral stability (roll stability), and not all airplanes meet this criterion.

There's a more fundamental point at play here though-- up to this point, this answer has addressed an airplane's tendency, or lack thereof, to *roll into a banked turn*.  But even in an aircraft with strong "lateral stability" or "roll stability", that will roll back to wings-level after any temporary disturbance, ***there is no tendency for the heading to stay constant over the long run***.  Each time the bank angle is slightly disturbed, the heading will change a little bit as the airplane turns slightly.  Expecting the heading to stay perfectly constant over the long run, is like flipping a coin a hundred times and expecting to come up with an exactly 50/50 split between "heads" and "tails".  Just as if you had a car that was correctly aligned so that it had no tendency to turn-- if you drove out on a flat dry lakebed where you could let the car run for miles on end without touching the steering wheel, you wouldn't expect the car to to end up heading in exactly the same direction it started out on, unless perhaps it was following a rutted track left by another vehicle.  In essence, an airplane with positive "roll stability" or "lateral stability" "knows" which way is up and actively returns to wings-level after a disturbance, but it has no way to "know" which direction it was travelling before that disturbance.<sup>2</sup>

Footnotes:

1. The angle-of-attack actually tends to decrease somewhat as the bank angle increases and the flight path curves, but not nearly enough to stop the airspeed from increasing.
2. An anecdote-- I once watched a novice radio-control flyer fly his model airplane-- he was constantly trimming the rudder, and I asked him why.  He said "well, I want it to keep flying into the wind when I take my hands of the sticks, but it won't.  It wants to turn out of the wind."  He thought that he could trim the plane *to hold a desired heading*, and he was mis-interpreting the plane's random deviation from the desired heading as a specific tendency to turn downwind.  It doesn't work that way-- the best the pilot can do is to trim out any *tendency to enter a banked turn*, so that it will tend to return to wings-level after any slight disturbance.  He can't trim the plane to hold a specific heading.  By changing the rudder trim whenever the airplane randomly wandered to a slightly different heading, the pilot was actually interfering with, not enhancing, the airplane's inherent "roll stability" or tendency to return to wings-level after a disturbance.  A pilot should trim to remove any *consistent rolling or turning tendency*, not in response to any random deviation from the desired heading.

Comment: If we want to really get carried away, we could consider cases where an airplane with neutral or negative roll stability is trimmed to be perfectly balanced in roll, and air is perfectly smooth, and wings are perfectly level, to such a perfect extent that there is absolutely no initial roll/turning tendency (like a pin perfectly balanced on its point), but after flying a sufficient amount of time in an appropriate direction with zero pitch, yaw, or roll rotation as seen from a valid inertial reference frame, the earth's rotation has caused the airplane to become banked relative to the horizon!